# Optaplanner Maven Archetype

Tags: java, maven, optaplanner, archetypes

Is there any Maven Archetype to create new Optaplanner based project (If yes can anyone point me to the repo) ? It will be helpful for updating to latest release versions.

Comment: There are no archetypes that I know of currently. It would be nice to have (although it's very hard to keep maven archtives from going stale). An alternative way is to copy paste `optaplanner-examples` or `optaplanner-webexamples` and delete everything you don't need.